# Why does my MPMoviePlayerController suddenly change load state to unknown?

Tags: iphone, ios4

My app is a digital magazine consisting of many pages. Some pages have video embedded in them.
I am using MPMoviePlayerViewController for the video playback.

The problem is that once I get to any page where the next page also contains a video then the video appears briefly then blanks out.
I've switched out video files, so I know it isn't the files themselves.

When the page loads offscreen ready to be scrolled into view the load state changes to 3 = MPMovieLoadStatePlayable + MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK (all good). Then when a second MPMoviePlayerController is loaded, the load state of the original suddenly changes to 0 (MPMovieLoadStateUnknown).

In the docs for MPMoviePlayerController it says

> Note: Although you can create multiple
>   MPMoviePlayerController objects and
>   present their views in your interface,
>   only one movie player at a time can
>   play its movie.

I read this to mean I can't play more than one at a time but does this it also mean I can't even load up more than one movie at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you can't even load more than one MPMoviePlayerController at a time. You can create the object but if you supply a URL to more than one then one will get unloaded.

Comment: Where did you find info about this behaviour? I've got the same problem in my App...

Comment: By observation of the playback state I think